# adb pull on large number of files

Tags: android, adb

I would like to pull the photos and videos from my Android phone. Unfortunately the USB port is broken, so I am using adb over wifi. I have around 3500 files in the camera folder and 35 GB.
I was able to connect and pull individual photos. However the connection is pretty slow. When I use `adb -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:abcde pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/` on the whole folder, it takes a few minutes to build a file list and then I end up with only a handful of pictures.
I am on a Windows 10 machine, but also have Ubuntu available if that makes things easier.

How can I reliably pull all the files in the folder? And how can I make the connection more stable, I have quite a few breaks of the connection (which got better after disabling the lock screen).

Comment: why not run an FTP server on the phone?

Comment: lack of knowledge :-)

Comment: how would I do that? There is a ton of filesharing apps, but I would like to avoid shady looking apps.

Comment: Solid Explorer has it, it will also keep the phone from sleeping while the server is active

Comment: thanks. I am trying right now, but it is also not flawless

Comment: Not sure if it would work better in your case but for transferring more than a few files over adb there are projects like [better-adb-sync](https://github.com/jb2170/better-adb-sync). But syncing files over Wifi is always a bit slow. The most reliable non-Wifi and non-USB way would be to use an sd-card inserted into the phone.